# Create an address book based on specific OU's

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

How can I create an address book in Exchange 2010 that includes users from specific OU's?

For example:

```
DomainA
    OU-1
    OU-2
    OU-3
        Sub-OU3-1
        Sub-OU3-2
        Sub-OU3-3
    OU-4
    OU-5
```

I want to create an address book that only includes OU-2, OU-3 (Including sub OU's 1-3) and OU-4. I want to exclude all other OU's (in this case OU-1 and OU-5).

What would be the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Default *Global Address List* (GAL) every mail enabled object in the forest. From [Understanding Address Lists](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232119(v=exchg.141).aspx):

> **Default Global Address List**   This address list contains all
>   mail-enabled users, contacts, groups, or rooms in the organization.
>   During setup, Exchange creates various default address lists. The most
>   familiar address list is the GAL. By default, the GAL contains all
>   recipients in an Exchange organization. In other words, any
>   mailbox-enabled or mail-enabled object in an Active Directory forest
>   that has Exchange installed is listed in the GAL.

You can create additional GALs using [`New-GlobalAddressList` cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/email-addresses-and-address-books/New-GlobalAddressList?view=exchange-ps) in Exchange Management Shell. That's the only method available, and a user can only have one GAL.

As `[-RecipientContainer <OrganizationalUnitIdParameter>]` can only have one OU, your should

- modify your OU structure, e.g.

  ```
  DomainA
      OU-Container-A
          OU-1
          OU-5
      OU-Container-B
          OU-2
          OU-3
              Sub-OU3-1
              Sub-OU3-2
              Sub-OU3-3
          OU-4
  ```
- use another filter like `-ConditionalDepartment`.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Esa, we recommend to redesign your OU structure.
Or, you can set a special value for an attribute, for example: department.
Then, use this attribute to filter recipient, and create a new **Address List**.

If we deploy GAL, we need to deploy [**ABP**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh529948(v=exchg.141).aspx) (**Address Boook Policy**) in your environment.